# What about "Write apps for all Ubuntu devices "

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

on http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/phone/app-ecosystem ubuntu writes about creating one app for all devices, seperated only by the currently offered UI ( Tablet, Phone, Desktop ).

Due desktop apps are using quickly for development (gtk-based) and phone and tablet are using qml (qt-based), I really wonder how I should start porting a user interface for an existing native application.

Wether I created the core-application in quickly or as a commandline (which should be an advantage comparing to the quickly-solution I guess) I don't have a clue to *extend* this existing app to offer a phone/tablet interface if needed.

And how should I start if I want to write an app that shall be available on each form factor? I mean one core app and two or three UIs.

Both would be very interesting for me to understand how I can plan my development without having the need and anger of rewriting/multiplying the core of the app to work on all form factors.

Thanks for advice and if such information exists, post a link on the above page so a developer can get information about writing multi-platform apps.

Regards

André

Answer (score 1):

Writing your application in QT (especially QML 2.0) seems to be the only supported way on Ubuntu Touch right now. QML applications also run fine on the desktop, thus I would suggest it as common denominator.